# Auto login system?

Tags: php, autologin

How would I create a "Remember me?" sort of auto-login system? I have a greasemonkey script to display information on a different website with use of  tags, but I don't want the information potentially stolen, so I have a pre-existing login system that I'd like to have a "remember me" with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to implement a 'remember me' on a website you are creating? In that case, you need to create cookies with username and password which don't get destroyed upon logout. Check for the existence of these cookies, and if found verify and login the user.

If you're, on the other hand, asking how to be remembered on websites you frequent when they do not provide a 'remember me' function, the best I can think of is tell your browser to remember and enter your password on each visit.

Comment: I never store the password in a cookie, apart from it being a security risk you also have to maintain the cookie if the user changes their password. I usually store 2 cookies if remembered - their user ID and a unique string (token) that is assigned to each user when they are inserted into the database that is never seen or changed by them. You can then use these 2 pieces of data to log a user in.

Comment: I, of course, didn't mean to store a user's password in plain sight. I tend to store their hashed and salted password. Even if someone were to access your password hash, not only will they not have the salt, the odds of their user client and ip matching the one you last used are slim.  My 'password change' controller, updates both cookies and session variables

Comment: Yes but unless people are aware of how to securely hash passwords it's bad advice to recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

The logic could be

when a user clicks on remember me check-box, then save the id and pwd in cookie.

And you can check everytime if cookie there then you can automatically set the login sessions. so they don't have to fill the login form again.

Note : Remember to destroy the cookie when a user clicks on logout.

Comment: Please please please don't ever store the user's password in a cookie. Create a unique, random, long session key (after the user-supplied username and password are validated), copy that to your database and to their cookie, and validate them next time using that instead. It's very simple, low effort, and much more secure.